# Matplotlib log scale with limit turns off the bottom/up plot spine

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a log (base 2 ) plot but I keep getting a plot with no top/bottom border.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

def toK (array):
    return map (lambda x: x/1000.0, array)


yy = [2603.76, 41077.89,48961.74, 43471.14]
xx = [1,16,32,64]

ax = plt.subplot(221, axisbg = 'white')
ax.set_xlim(0, 128)


ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)



ax.plot( xx, toK(yy), label="0%", linestyle='--',  marker='o', clip_on = False)

plt.savefig('./tx2.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Unboder plit]

How can I do this correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have 0 as the limit while using a log scale. (`0` is at negative infinity on a log scale)

Setting the axis limits to include zero should arguably raise an error, but at the moment, it just silently causes some things to break.

If you want to have 0 on the plot, use `symlog` instead of log.  However, in this case, it probably makes a lot more sense to have the minimum be `2^-1` (i.e. 0.5) instead.

For example, either do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

yy = np.array([2603.76, 41077.89,48961.74, 43471.14])
xx = [1,16,32,64]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 128)

ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)

ax.plot(xx, yy / 1000, linestyle='--',  marker='o', clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or use a "symlog" instead of a log scale:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

yy = np.array([2603.76, 41077.89,48961.74, 43471.14])
xx = [1,16,32,64]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 128)

ax.set_xscale('symlog', basex=2)

ax.plot(xx, yy / 1000, linestyle='--',  marker='o', clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried symlog before but it fails when saving the plot.

Comment: @fabiim - How does it fail? Can you give some more details?